# Can't store class object with datetime in mongoDB using asp.net core

Tags: mongodb, api, asp.net-core

im working with an asp.net core web api, i was tasked with adding the MongoDB infraestructure, we already have an SQLserver infraestructure that works fine, and everyhing from the MongoDB infraestructure is working fine except the post method to store "Consulta", this is because it has a datetime attribute, but i havent been able to figure out to fix it, i keep getting this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Serializer
> for System.DateTime must implement IBsonDocumentSerializer to be used
> with LINQ.)

I tried implementing a Serializer but i don't have experience with this:

```
public class MyCustomDateTimeSerializer<TDateTime> : IBsonSerializer
    {
        static MyCustomDateTimeSerializer()
        {
            if (typeof(TDateTime) != typeof(DateTime) && typeof(TDateTime) != typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"MyCustomDateTimeSerializer could be used only with {nameof(DateTime)} or {nameof(Nullable<DateTime>)}");
            }
        }

        public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var dateTime = context.Reader.ReadDateTime();
            if (typeof(TDateTime) == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                if (dateTime == BsonConstants.UnixEpoch.Millisecond)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new DateTime(dateTime);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new DateTime(dateTime);
            }
        }

        public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                context.Writer.WriteInt64(BsonConstants.UnixEpoch.Millisecond);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Writer.WriteDateTime(((DateTime)value).Ticks);
            }
        }

        public Type ValueType => typeof(TDateTime);
    }
```

This is the code for the class:

```
namespace Consultorio.Dominio.Entidades
{
    [BsonCollection("Consultas")]
    public class Consulta:Entity
    {
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomDateTimeSerializer<DateTime>))]
        private DateTime _fechaConsulta;

        public DateTime FechaConsulta { 
            get
            {
                return _fechaConsulta;
            }
            set
            { 
                _fechaConsulta = value.LaterThatHour(1,"Fecha Consulta");
            }
        }

        private string _direccion;
        public string Direccion { 
            get { return _direccion; } 
            set { _direccion = value.Range(0, 30, nameof(_direccion)); } 
        }

        public string DoctorId { get; private set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; private set; }

        public string ClienteId { get; private set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; private set; }

        private Consulta()
        {

        }

        public Consulta(Cliente cliente, Doctor doctor,  DateTime fechaconsulta, string direccion = "")
        {
            FechaConsulta = fechaconsulta.LaterThatHour(1, "Fecha Consulta");
            Direccion = direccion.Range(0,30,nameof(direccion));
            DoctorId = doctor.Id;
            ClienteId = cliente.Id;
            Cliente = cliente;
            Doctor = doctor;

        }


    }
}
```

And this is where the program stops:

```
public async Task<List<Consulta>> GetCustormerDates(string clienteId, DateTime fecha)
        {
            var  citas = await _collection.Find(c => c.ClienteId == clienteId
                                            && c.FechaConsulta.Date == fecha.Date).ToListAsync();
            
            return  citas;
        }
```

Comment: Have you seen this post https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4415 ?  Also, you should set a breakpoint so that you can find out what additional exception(s) are occurring, as noted by the message: `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.`